# ¿Cómo enviar un parámetro a una función en JavaScript?

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, select

Tengo la siguiente función:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Unidades").on('change', function () {
        $("#Unidades option:selected").each(function () {
            var cadenaCCT = $(this).val();
            $.post("cargarPersonal.php",{cadenaCCT:cadenaCCT},function(data) {  
                $("#Personal").html(data);
            });         
        });
   });
});
```

Lo que hace es recargar un segundo `select` con el valor seleccionado, solo que tengo un problema, está inmerso en un *modal* que va cambiando de valor `modal1`, `modal2` y así sucesivamente... y ocupo que reciba como un parámetro o valor del *modal* *1*, *2*, *3* y así sucesivamente en la líneas donde tengo `#Unidades`.

```
$("#Unidades").on('change', function ()
```

... donde unidades quede `#Unidades1`, `Unidades2`, `Unidades3`, etc...

¿Cómo puedo realizar esto?

Comment: Deberias usar clases en lugar de ids

Comment: podrias colocar tu codigo html...

Comment: agrega un onclick en tu enlace (etiqueta "a") que lanza el modal y sobre eso puedes hacer lo que quieras extra

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que necesitas es, sustituir tu `<XXX id="Unidades"` para crear una clase *CSS* para marcar el elemento.

De esta forma, al hacer una modificación en tu código, podrá usarse en los elementos que marques con tu clase *CSS*.

Suponemos que la clase *CSS* para marcar es `"Unidades"`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Unidades").on('change', function () {
        $(".Unidades option:selected").each(function () {
            var cadenaCCT = $(this).val();
            $.post("cargarPersonal.php",{cadenaCCT:cadenaCCT},function(data) {
                $("#Personal").html(data);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Espero que con esto te acerques al fin que buscabas.

Comment: Rubén Espada, me podrías explicar de favor que es lo que interpreta el punto al cambiarlo  en  lugar del #  , Gracias

Comment: Si, en los selectores, para hacer referencia a una clase CSS, usas el ".", y cuando usas el "#" hace referencia al ID de un objeto. Si la clase para marcar fuera "marcarUnidades" debería poner $(".marcarUnidades")

Comment: ok voy a ver si cambiando el # por un punto hace algo diferente, Muchas Gracias

Comment: Buenas Cesar, acabo de mirar lo que puse, y no se entiende nada, porque por algún motivo, está recortado y se han perdido palabras.
Tienes que agregar una clase css a los elementos que quieras marcar, vamos, los que tenías el id=unidades

Comment: Ya hice un test y efectivamente no me funciono con el punto, tal cual tengo el codigo me esta funcionando a medias, tengo que abrir y cerrar en varias ocasiones los modales para que cargue la alerta y con eso ya se que funciona,  un compañero me dijo que por que no intentaba renombrar la funcion que recarga los selects, es decir si se llama cargarSelect1, cargarSelect2 y asi sucesivamente en funcion del modal en el que va cargada la funcion en lugar de una funcion general denominada cargarSelect que es como la tengo ahorita... pero no tengo idea de como pegarle el valor numerico

Answer (score 0):

Realicé una sencilla modificación al código:

```
function cargarSelect(number){
    alert(number);
    $("#Unidades"+number).on('change', function () {
        alert("#Unidades"+number);
        $("#Unidades option:selected").each(function () {
            var cadenaCCT = $(this).val();
            $.post("cargarPersonal.php",{cadenaCCT:cadenaCCT},function(data) {
                $("#Personal"+number).html(data);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Obtengo los valores que vienen después de cada clic, con los alert, solo para confirmar que sean correctos. Esto sin problema, el único detalle es que no he podido modificar la línea...

```
$("#Unidades option:selected").each(function () {}
```

... para que actúe la función. Tengo un severo detalle con el uso de las comillas dobles (`""`), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Después de intentar varias cosas logré dejar esta función así:

```
function cargarSelect(number){
    $("#Unidades"+number).on('change', function () {
            $("#Unidades"+number+" option:selected").each(function(){ 
            var cadenaCCT = $(this).val();
            $.post("cargarPersonal.php",{cadenaCCT:cadenaCCT},function(data) {
                $("#Personal"+number).html(data);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

El único detalle es que no me carga correctamente para todos los modales, en ocasiones carga bien en tres modales, en dos no, al cerrar la aplicación y limpiar el *buffer del explorador* y volver a cargar, puede que funcione bien en dos modales y el resto no... y así al azar es funcional en alguna de las ventanas modales y en otras no.

Comment: Pienso que deberías combinar tus dos respuestas en una sola y borrar una de las dos.

Comment: Gracias por la observación @ArtEze a lo mejor edito esta "respuesta" en función de lo que logre resolver que ya me tiene hasta ...este tema